# I am Getting warning 'setLineBreakMode: is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 3.0' any alternate for this?

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode8

I am using react native when i run the project from xCode i see the warning message setLineBreakMode: is Deprecated first deprecated in iOS 3.0.
here is the line i used the setLineBreakMode in my code

[clearButton setLineBeakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];

Any alternate or solution's welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
```